# Stripe Wallet for add and withdraw money and History of transactions

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe for payment gateway,
on my portal, there are multiple users I want to create a node.js api where each user can see their wallet amount and withdraw money and also can see their transaction history, they can pay someone in the portal amount from the wallet
I'm using node.js and react.js for this

Does anyone has the solution

Comment: You can start exploring Stripe Connect for this: 
https://stripe.com/docs/connect
But there is no native/built-in feature for building Wallets for customers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.